# After Wordpress and ACF version upgrade the ACF flexible content layout field is not storing in the database

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields, ampersand, acfpro

In our application, we are using multiple ACF flexible content layout fields but one of the flexible content layout fields is not storing into the database. That ACF flexible content layout field name is given like "product_category_&_series".

Is this because of the ampersand(special character &) is there in ACF field name?

This issue happens in the production environment. After upgraded both Wordpress from 4.8 to 5.1 and ACFPro from 5.6 to 5.8 and deployed to the production environment. And could not able to reproduce the Stage and Dev environments.

Can anyone be having the same please let us share?

Comment: you mean the problem is only occuring on Production environment and not on Stage or Dev?

Comment: Yes gael, It is only production environment

Comment: so there could be differences between server language implementation. Maybe utf-8 is not supported in your database which breaks the code. I would try creating a flexible field without ampersand in name and check if it works.

Comment: If we create a flexible field without ampersand, the old data will lost. That means we have already created data with this field "product_category_&_series". After version upgrade (WP & ACF) this field is not storing in the database that to production environment only